# C DLL to Python Callback

Tags: python, c++, c, dll, callback

I have a Visual C++ DLL. I have a SetCallback( function-pointer) exported in the DLL.
I use this function to set a callback function from a python2.7 script. I follow what is given in the Python documentation.

```
from ctypes import *
def mypy_callback(number):
    print str(number)

d = cdll.LoadLibrary(r"myfunctions.dll")
callback_type = CFUNCTYPE(None, c_int )
d.SetCallback(callback_type(mypy_callback))
```

In the C code I have

```
typedef void (*callback_function)(int);
void SetCallback(callback_function aCallback)
{
    py_callback = aCallback;
}
```

When I call this function from C DLL, like so: py_callback(999), python just crashes.
What could I be doing wrong?

Comment: Is the `callback_type` variable still in scope when the callback happens?

Comment: Yes. The callback_type is very much in scope. And some of the seemingly obvious errors like prototype, parameter/return value mismatch etc have been ruled out. My colleague (working remotely) tried the same DLL using a C# callback and it works for him. I dont know C#, so don't know if it makes sense to compare that with my python code.

Comment: It works for me. I used VS2008 and inserted the call in `SetCallback`. The code you posted is not complete as it never calls the callback, which makes me wonder what else there may be. Are you able to reproduce the problem in a minimal, freshly created C project?

Answer (score 2):

The following callback indirection will solve this problem:

```
d = cdll.LoadLibrary(r"myfunctions.dll")
callback_type = CFUNCTYPE(None, c_int )
callback = callback_type(mypy_callback)
d.SetCallback(callback)
```

Comment: Thanks a lot, but could please explain why there must be a callback variable? In what way is trouble connected to its scope?

Comment: Ok, this note in ctypes docs explains: "Make sure you keep references to CFUNCTYPE() objects as long as they are used from C code. ctypes doesn’t, and if you don’t, they may be garbage collected, crashing your program when a callback is made."